# Wordpress Loop with Bootstrap grid. How to optimize this code?

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]
[image]

In first img code is working with posts == 5
In second image code getting broken if posts == 3 
.row doenst close

How to use wordpress Lopp with Bootstrap grid I wanna to know the best way to optimize my code.  This code work correctly but I wanna just to optimize this code I think this isn't the best solution. Please show me how I can optimize this code. Thank you.

```html
<div class="container">
<?php
$args = [
  'post_status'            => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'         => 6,
  'no_found_rows'          => true,
   ];

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

if ( $query->current_post === 0 )
{
echo '<div class="row">';
   echo '<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">'; ?>
      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'post 1' ); ?>>
         <figure>
           <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?>
         <figure>
         <div class="entry">
            <div class="entry-title">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
         </div>
      </article>
    <?php
    echo '</div>'; 
    }

if ( $query->current_post === 1 )
{
echo '<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">'; ?>
   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'post 2' ); ?>>
         <figure>
           <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?>
         <figure>
         <div class="entry">
            <div class="entry-title">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
         </div>
    </article>
<?php
}

if ( $query->current_post === 2 )
{ ?>
      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'post 3' ); ?>>
         <figure>
           <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?>
         <figure>
         <div class="entry">
            <div class="entry-title">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
         </div>
      </article>
<?php
}

if ( $query->current_post === 3 )
{ ?>
      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'post 4' ); ?>>
         <figure>
           <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?>
         <figure>
         <div class="entry">
            <div class="entry-title">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
         </div>
      </article>
<?php
echo '</div>';  
echo '</div>';  
}

endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <div class="exerpt">
            exerpt
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
         <article class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                title
            </div>
         </article>
         <article class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                title
            </div>
         </article>
         <article class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                title
            </div>
         </article>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        post-4
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        post-5
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write the same part of code each time you check a condition.

```
<div class="container">
<?php
$args = [
  'post_status'            => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'         => 6,
  'no_found_rows'          => true,
   ];

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

$post_num = strval($query->current_post + 1);
$post_count = wp_count_posts()->publish;

if ( $query->current_post === 0 || $query->current_post === 4 ) : ?>
    <div class="row">;
<?php ;endif; ?>

<?php if ( $query->current_post === 0  || $query->current_post === 1 || $query->current_post === 4 || $query->current_post === 5 ) : ?>
        <div class="col-lg-6">'
<?php ;endif; ?>

      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $post_num ); ?>>
        <figure>
              <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?>
         </figure>

         <?php if ( $query->current_post === 0) : ?>
         <div class="post_excerpt">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div> 
        <?php ;endif; ?>

         <div class="entry">
            <div class="entry-title">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
         </div>
      </article>

<?php if ( $query->current_post === 0 || $query->current_post === 3 || $query->current_post === 4 || $query->current_post === 5 || $query->current_post === $post_count-1 ) : ?>
    </div>
<?php ;endif; ?>

<?php if ( $query->current_post === 3 || $query->current_post === 5 || $query->current_post === $post_count-1 ) : ?>   
  </div>
<?php ;endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I wanna for current_post === 0 change content and style how do it ? Thank you

Comment: For example add post+excerpt where post == 0

Comment: No into article for post 0 dear Dmitry

Comment: I wanna to put excerpt into article for post 0
post 1 || 2 || 3 without excerpt

Comment: Ok I see 
Thank you very much

Comment: Soory Dear Dmitry its broken if posts < 5 what can I do ?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is broken?

Comment: if ( $query->current_post === 3 ) : ?>   
  </div>
  ;endif; 
if === 2 div doesnt close

Comment: Please take a look at the edited question I've put html code which I wanna to get

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer. It has to work for you now.

Comment: Bro SORRY but I cant understant why if post == 3 or < 3 my .row dont close and code getting broken but if post >3 its all OK

Comment: Notice
: Undefined variable: post_count in

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the variable. Corrected.

Comment: Its work but again if post ==3 its all braken 
thanks for all

Comment: Can you provide the html code you get when you have just 3 posts?

Comment: I have add imgs with 6 post where it work correctly and second image show 3 post and my code getting broken 
.col-md-4 getting down

Comment: I edited my answer. It seems I found the problem. `$query->count_post` starts with 0. If it doesn't work try to put `$post_count = wp_count_posts()->publish;` outside the while loop